# SQL Server : 'Not valid identifier' when using PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, dynamic-sql

I have a temp table `#temproles` with data like this:

| ID | Dept | RoleCode | RoleName | NameOf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 65576 | 1 | CLP | Frank |
| 123456 | 65576 | 2 | SUH | Susan |
| 234567 | 65578 | 2 | SUH | Susan |
| 234567 | 65576 | 13 | CLH | Alison |

I am trying to use PIVOT to return a dataset like this

| ID | Dept | CLP | SUH | CLH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 65576 | Frank | Susan | NULL |
| 234567 | 65578 | NULL | Susan | Alison |

This is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT 
    @ColumnName = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(rolename, '''')
FROM #temproles
GROUP BY id, rolename
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SET @DynamicPivotQuery =
    N'SELECT id, dept,' + @ColumnName + N' FROM 
    (
        SELECT id, dept, rolename, nameOf
        FROM #temproles
    ) x
    PIVOT 
    (
        ISNULL(nameOf, '''')
        FOR rolename IN (' + @ColumnName + N')
    ) p'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

This returns the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
> Incorrect syntax near 'BDA'.

I previously was using `EXEC @DynamicPivotQuery` but got an error where the:

> name of N'SELECT id, dept, etc.. was not a valid identifier.

My understanding is this was not correct so I changed it to `EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

For reference

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(cdservicingrolecode, '''')
FROM #JLtemproles
GROUP BY uniqpolicy, cdservicingrolecode
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
```

returns

```
'BDA','BDP','CMW','BRC','CXA','CXH','BRP','SUH','CXP','BDH','CLP','BDL','PLH','CLH','SUP','PLP','BIP','BDS','CMP','CLA'
```

Comment: If you print the generated SQL, I suspect the issue will popup.   That said.  use QUOTENAME(rolename) (no quotes)  so the columns would be [BDA],[CLP] with square brackets

Comment: Worth pointing out that the syntax error is **near** `'BDA'`, it's not necessarily the `'BDA'` itself. Have you tried to print the SQL query and copy-paste it to a new tab in SSMS to see what's wrong with it? But in SQL Server the `'` is used to delimit string literals - you either want to use `[]` around your column names or `"`  if `SET QUOTEDIDENTIFIER ON` is in effect.

Comment: Just to be clear  QUOTENAME(rolename)  NOT  QUOTENAME(rolename, '''')

Comment: My guess is the issue is what you have inside the PIVOT itself. You are only allowed to put column identifiers into the PIVOT statement and nothing else. The `ISNULL(nameof, '''')` is not allowed I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the query. The `PIVOT` needs an aggregate function, so `ISNULL()` will not work. I replaced it with `MIN()`. The role names also need to be enclosed in brackets rather than quotes. Here is the code along with my temp table test.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temproles
CREATE TABLE #temproles (ID INT, Dept INT, RoleCode INT, RoleName VARCHAR(3), NameOf VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #temproles
SELECT 123456, 66576, 1, 'CLP', 'Frank'
UNION ALL SELECT 123456, 66576, 2, 'SUH', 'Susan'
UNION ALL SELECT 234567, 65578, 2, 'SUH', 'Susan'
UNION ALL SELECT 234567, 65576, 13, 'CLH', 'Alison'

DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ColumnName = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',[' + rolename + ']'
                FROM #temproles
                GROUP BY id, rolename
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
SELECT @ColumnName

SET @DynamicPivotQuery =
    N'SELECT id, dept,' + @ColumnName + N' FROM 
    (
        SELECT id, dept, rolename, nameOf
        FROM #temproles
    ) x
    PIVOT 
    (
        MIN(nameOf)
        FOR rolename IN (' + @ColumnName + N')
    ) p'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Comment: bless you this did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: You are very welcome. I'm glad it helped you and hope it helps others as well.